# Javascript function - if specific text then use a defined number in new function

Tags: javascript, forms, acrobat

I'm trying to return a value in acrobat depending on two other fields - one text and one a value.

Users select from a drop down box the frequency in box F1, I then need to turn this text into a number to then multiply by another box (X1) , depending on the text selected in F1.

So far I have attempted this but can't get the result I would expect. Your assistance would be appreciated, I've very new to javascript! Many thanks.

```
var frequency_values= new Array();
frequency_value["Monthly"]=12;
frequency_value["Quarterly"]=4;
frequency_value["Semi-annually"]=2;
frequency_value["Annually"]=1;


document.getElementById("F1").value = frequency_value;

g.value = this.getField('frequency_value');
h.value = this.getField("X1");

event.value = (h.value * g.value)/52;
```

Comment: `frequency_value` is an array.  You need to get a single element *from* that array first.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?  Where are `frequency_value`, `g`, or `h` defined?

Comment: Please provide your html as well.

Comment: http://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/

Comment: This is all I have. It's to go in a custom calculation script within Adobe Acrobat X Pro. F1 is the drop down where users select the frequency of payments, X1 is the payment and the calculation is meant to give the result of a weekly equivalent (one times the other (once frequency is converted to a number) divided by 52 weeks). Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function getField(f) {
  // not sure what getField does in your app, but i'm just defining it here and return a number for debugging in console
  return 20;
}

var frequencyValues = {
  'Monthly': 12,
  'Quarterly': 4,
  'Semi-annually': 2,
  'Annually': 1
};

// lets get the user selection form the select drop down
// var f1 = document.getElementById('F1').value;
var f1 = 'Monthly';   // for debugging in our console, lets just set it to monthly

// not sure what g and h are, but we'll just define them here
var g = {},
    h = {};

g.value = frequencyValues[f1];
h.value = this.getField('X1');

var value = (h.value * g.value) / 52;

console.log(value);
```

The idea is to create an object named frequencyValues, not array.
And when you access it, you access it using obj[field].

Since I don't have your code, so I created the getField function and commented our the document.getElementById, but I think you get the idea.

BTW, not sure what your language background is, but try to stick to camel standard you code Javascript, ie. frequencyValues instead of frequency_values.  Try to avoid underscore in variables and function names at all costs.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks @Will. I have zero background in javascript!  I'm just trying to get a PDF in Adobe Acrobat X to do what I want :)  The code above doesn't work but I don't know why.